# mvn command not found with environment variables set

Tags: bash, macos, maven, terminal

Currently I am experiencing a problem with maven on my Mac OSx 10.10.5 Yosemite.

I installed the apache files today, and tried to set maven up only for it to not recognize itself.

I currently have a ~.bash_profile file with the three lines:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export M2_HOME=/Users/vincenttomie/apache-maven-3.6.1/
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:/Users/vincenttomie/apache-maven- 
3.6.1/bin
```

When I do $Java_Home I get

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home
```

When I do $M2_HOME I get

```
/Users/vincenttomie/apache-maven-3.6.1/
```

When I do echo $PATH I get below

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/vincenttomie/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin:/Users/vincenttomie/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/vincenttomie/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin
```

When I try to do mvn -- version in the terminal it gives me the

```
~bash: mvn: command not found.
```

I was wondering if anyone knew what the problem could be.

Thank you!

Comment: `M2_HOME` is not needed. Only entry in PATH. Afterwards you need to reopen the terminal that `.bash_profile` will be executed.

Comment: It has to do with PATH variable only. Have you tried to cd into the $M2_HOME/bin and run the mvn command ?.

Comment: @khmarbaise if the output of $PATH is from current session then mvn should be available in the terminal for it to use the binary, right ? Seems to me some issue with installation